# How to check for stuck data in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

**This question has been edited for clarity based on the comments**

Objective: Flag variable number of stuck/repetitive values in the columns of a data frame based on a group.

Desired Solution: The desired solution should meet the following criteria:

1. Speed and Brevity are important
2. Solution should accept as input variable number of thresholds for flagging stuck/repetitive values for each zone.
   For e.g. : {"Zone1": 4 , "Zone2":2} -> indicating that in Zone1, there need to be 4 consecutive repeated values for the logic to flag, while in Zone2, having atleast 2 or more repeated values should trigger the flag
3. Please add comments wherever possible to make it easier to understand
4. Preferably use Pandas and/or Numpy
5. Time your solution on a test data frame with 87600 values (generate a data frame with 87,600 values to time)

Input Data/ Problem Formulation:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from random import randint

# Generate some random data
ts_index = pd.date_range("1/1/2019", periods=24, freq="1H")
v1 = [randint(1, 100) for i in range(24)]
v2 = [2] * 24
v3 = [2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 0, 2, 2, 1, 9, 2, 4, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 8, 1, 7, 3, 5]
test_df = pd.DataFrame({"v1": v1, "v2": v2, "v3": v3}, index=ts_index)
print(test_df)
```

Now, a sample output should look like this.
[image]

Comment: Hi, could help, but 2 problems at the same time are not really good for future readers. Also the titel could be modified to be more helpful for future readers. Also please provide a very compact input and corresponding output dataframe (no unneccesarry code or columns) e.g. like your random dataframe but alread including those "zones" and with descriptive column names and no unnecassary columns.

Comment: I see some inconsistency in your output, why `6:00` is `FALSE` in `v3` but `4:00` is `TRUE`? Is the current row included in the repetitions? Please explain.

Comment: Assuming you are referring to data in column v3 at hour 4 you are correct, they should be FALSE at hour 4 and hour 5 since we are looking for 4 repeated values to trigger the flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we get the absolute difference for the columns, followed by a `cumsum()`.

Assuming that if a value does not change, the cumulative sum of the differences will remain constant, we can use pandas `.shift()`.

We have to compare each value in zone1 with the one 4 rows above. Similar for zone2.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime


# Generate some random data
ts_index = pd.date_range("1/1/2019", periods=24, freq="1H")
v1 = [random.randint(1, 100) for i in range(24)]
v2 = [2] * 24
v3 = [2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 0, 2, 2, 1, 9, 2, 4, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 8, 1, 7, 3, 5]
df = pd.DataFrame({"v1": v1, "v2": v2, "v3": v3}, index=ts_index)
df1 = df.diff().fillna(0)

# Add hour and time of day to create flag
df['Hour'] = df.index.hour
df['Flag'] = np.where((df['Hour'] <= 8) | (df['Hour'] >= 18), 'Zone1', 'Zone2')
df1['Flag'] = np.where((df['Hour'] <= 8) | (df['Hour'] >= 18), 'Zone1', 'Zone2')

df1[["v1", "v2","v3"]] = np.abs(df1[["v1", "v2","v3"]])
df1[["v1", "v2","v3"]] = df1.groupby("Flag")["v1", "v2","v3"].cumsum()
columns = ["v1","v2","v3"]

z1_p = 3
z2_p = 1

for col in columns:
    df["Flag_"+col] = (np.array(df1[col].shift(z1_p) == df1[col]) & np.array(df1["Flag"] == "Zone1")) | \
(np.array(df1[col].shift(z2_p) == df1[col]) & np.array(df1["Flag"] == "Zone2"))
    for element in df[df["Flag_"+col] == True].index:
        if df.loc[element]["Flag"] == "Zone1":
            for i in range(1,4):
                a = a.append(pd.Index([element - datetime.timedelta(hours=i)]))
        else:
            a = a.append(pd.Index([element - datetime.timedelta(hours=1)]))
    df.at[a,"Flag_"+col] = True

df
```

**Output:**

```
                    v1  v2  v3  Hour    Flag    Flag_v1 Flag_v2 Flag_v3
2019-01-01 00:00:00 31  2   2   0       Zone1   False   True    True
2019-01-01 01:00:00 93  2   2   1       Zone1   False   True    True
2019-01-01 02:00:00 48  2   2   2       Zone1   False   True    True
2019-01-01 03:00:00 56  2   2   3       Zone1   False   True    True
2019-01-01 04:00:00 9   2   4   4       Zone1   False   True    False
2019-01-01 05:00:00 75  2   4   5       Zone1   False   True    False
2019-01-01 06:00:00 29  2   0   6       Zone1   False   True    False
2019-01-01 07:00:00 61  2   2   7       Zone1   False   True    False
2019-01-01 08:00:00 64  2   2   8       Zone1   False   True    False
2019-01-01 09:00:00 82  2   1   9       Zone2   False   True    False
2019-01-01 10:00:00 13  2   9   10      Zone2   False   True    False
2019-01-01 11:00:00 97  2   2   11      Zone2   False   True    False
2019-01-01 12:00:00 74  2   4   12      Zone2   False   True    False
2019-01-01 13:00:00 26  2   1   13      Zone2   False   True    False
2019-01-01 14:00:00 77  2   2   14      Zone2   False   True    True
2019-01-01 15:00:00 39  2   2   15      Zone2   False   True    True
2019-01-01 16:00:00 79  2   0   16      Zone2   False   True    False
2019-01-01 17:00:00 35  2   2   17      Zone2   False   True    False
2019-01-01 18:00:00 65  2   1   18      Zone1   False   True    False
2019-01-01 19:00:00 74  2   8   19      Zone1   False   True    False
2019-01-01 20:00:00 72  2   1   20      Zone1   False   True    False
2019-01-01 21:00:00 23  2   7   21      Zone1   False   True    False
2019-01-01 22:00:00 28  2   3   22      Zone1   False   True    False
2019-01-01 23:00:00 59  2   5   23      Zone1   False   True    False
```

Comment: Thank you for your attempt, but the result is very different from what I was asking for. I will be updating my original post to reflect the expected output accordingly

Comment: Provide an example output and we will see then

Comment: Please post the entire solution with proper references. In its current form, I am unable to get it to work, I think there are a few typos where you are referring to a column Flag which may or may not exist. I don't know what df1 is ? please clean that so I can actually test it. Also, I want the current row to be included - just answering your previous question

Comment: There you have it.

Comment: I followed your guidance and removed .shift(1) and also reduced z1_p and z2_p by 1 each. While the result is close, it still has some issues. I am flagging them on the screenshot. https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6dhJ.png

Comment: The first ones are ok (you do not have anything above, so you should discard them). If you need 2 consecutives, you will have the current row and the one above, so the next cases you mark are ok (otherwise improve your description). The ones in zone2 are ok (you said you need 4 consecutives isn't it?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219368/discussion-between-uguntupalli-and-lets-try).

Answer (score 1):

Will this Work

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
from random import randint


def processGroup(zone, ZoneGroup):
    ZoneGroup.sort_index(inplace=True)
    repeatation = repeatations[zone]
    
    repeat_counts = [0]*len(cols)
    previous_value = [None]*len(cols)
    
    for i, record in ZoneGroup.iterrows():
        for j, c in enumerate(cols):
            if previous_value[j] == record[c]:
                repeat_counts[j] += 1
            else:
                repeat_counts[j] = 0
                
            if repeat_counts[j] >= repeatation:
                test_df.at[i, c+'RepeatFlag']=True
                
            previous_value[j] = record[c]

TotalRecords = 87600 #24*10
ts_index = pd.date_range("1/1/2019", periods=TotalRecords, freq="1H")
v1 = [randint(1, 2) for i in range(TotalRecords)]
v2 = [randint(1, 3) for i in range(TotalRecords)]
v3 = [randint(1, 5) for i in range(TotalRecords)]

test_df = pd.DataFrame({"v1": v1, "v2": v2, "v3": v3}, index=ts_index)
test_df['Zone'] = pd.Series(test_df.index).apply(lambda t: 'Zone'+ str(int((t.hour+t.minute/60+t.second/3600)// 8 + 1))).to_list()

# You can tweak repaet values here
repeatations = {'Zone1':4, 'Zone2':3, 'Zone3':2}
cols = test_df.columns[:-1]

#test_df[cols+'RepeatFlag']=False
for c in cols+'RepeatFlag':
    test_df[c]=False

for i, g in test_df.groupby('Zone'):
    processGroup(i, g)
    
print(test_df)
repeat_df = test_df[test_df.v1RepeatFlag | test_df.v2RepeatFlag | test_df.v3RepeatFlag]
print(repeat_df)
```

Comment: Kuldip, 
      Your code raises a Key Error .
KeyError: "None of [Index(['v1RepeatFlag', 'v2RepeatFlag', 'v3RepeatFlag'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Comment: I have tested it in Jupyter Notebook, Maybe **test_df[cols+'RepeatFlag']=False** does't work because of pandas version difference. Please try edited code.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the code. Look at the screenshot of the Notebook. Try the edited code for once.
[image: screen shot of the notebook]